# Why won't my buttons hide? (JavaScript Functions/CSS Visibility)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't really get this. I tried to hide the three buttons with CSS in my JavaScript example, but nothing happened at all! Why won't li.two and li.three hide? I want to make it so that li.two and li.three aren't visible until their button is clicked. (Yahoo is only visible when Google is clicked, Facebook is only visible when Yahoo is clicked) Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_prompt()
{
var name=prompt("Your Name");
if (name!=null && name!="")
  {
  alert("Thanks for clicking " + name + "!");
  window.open("http://www.google.com/};
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert()
{
alert("Thanks for clicking me!");
window.open("http://www.yahoo.com/");
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert1()
{
alert("Have fun on Facebook!");
window.open("http://www.facebook.com/");
}
</script>
<script type="css/text">
li.two, li.three {display:none};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li class="one"><input type="button" onclick="show_prompt();showNext('Yahoo')" value="Google" />
<li class="two"><input type="button" id="Yahoo" onclick="show_alert();showNext('Facebook')" value="Yahoo" />
<li class="three"><input type="button" id="Facebook" onclick="show_alert1()"value="Facebook" />
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have each of the functions in its own `<script>` block? Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

You have no closing tags on the `<li>`

```
<li class="one"><input type="button" onclick="show_prompt();showNext('Yahoo')" value="Google" /></li>
<li class="two"><input type="button" id="Yahoo" onclick="show_alert();showNext('Facebook')" value="Yahoo" /></li>
<li class="three"><input type="button" id="Facebook" onclick="show_alert1()"value="Facebook" /></li>
```

Your CSS is wrong, `;` is outside the `{}`

`li.two, li.three {display:none;}`

And your css is in a `<script>` tag, needs to be inside:

`<style type="text/css">li.two, li.three {display:none;}</style>`

Comment: It still doesn't seem to hide the other two buttons.

Comment: Oh wait I see the problem. Never mind- You were right. Thanks :D

Comment: I changed script to style and nothing happened again :-(

Comment: Wait no it worked. Sorry about all the... changes. In the end, you were right. Thanks!

Comment: <style type="text/css"> 
li.two, li.three {display:none;}
</style>

Comment: @loddn, whats the difference between mine and yours? and no prbolem KeybordPiano (btw your names spelt wrong ;))

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this

```
<li class="one"><input type="button" onclick="show_prompt();showNext('Yahoo')" value="Google" />
<li class="two"><input type="hidden" type="button" id="Yahoo" onclick="show_alert();showNext('Facebook')" value="Yahoo" />
<li class="three"><input type="hidden" type="button" id="Facebook" onclick="show_alert1()"value="Facebook" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not closed li tag ,your showNext() function call only , didn't write that function

try this

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        .two,.three{
        display:none;
        }
        </style>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        function show_prompt()
        {
        var name=prompt("Your Name");
        if (name!=null && name!="")
          {
          alert("Thanks for clicking " + name + "!");
          window.open("http://www.google.com/")

          };
        }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function showNext(value){

        document.getElementById(value).style.display="block";





        }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function show_alert()
        {
        alert("Thanks for clicking me!");
        window.open("http://www.yahoo.com/");
        }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function show_alert1()
        {
        alert("Have fun on Facebook!");
        window.open("http://www.facebook.com/");
        }
        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
        <ul>
        <li class="one"><input type="button" onclick="show_prompt();showNext('Yahoo')" value="Google" /></li>
        <li class="two" id="Yahoo" ><input type="button" id="Yahoo" onclick="show_alert();showNext('Facebook')" value="Yahoo" /></li>
        <li class="three" id="Facebook"><input type="button" id="Facebook" onclick="show_alert1()"value="Facebook" /></li>
        </ul>
        </body>
        </html>
```